# how can I use UIWebview as always working on background

Tags: iphone, xcode, multithreading, uiwebview, background

I would like to set `UIWebview` always running on background.
`UIWebview` is not working when iPhone entered '`applicationDidEnterBackground`'.
so I want `UIWebview` to run always on backgroud.
Is it possible?

Comment: I think [this link][1] may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323634/ios-application-executing-tasks-in-background

Answer (score 2):

Every app can continue to execute in the background for roughly 10 minutes before it terminates. Only certain apps can continue to execute in the background, such as audio/gps/bluetooth etc related apps. You can find out more [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).

The following code sample is from the app doc and can help you get started -

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```