# How to check if connection has been switched to 3G while app is in background in iOS?

Tags: ios, networking, background-process, reachability, nsurlsession

Is it Possible for an app to know whether the connection has been switched from Wi-Fi to 3G    While app is in background?The requirement is that download should happen on Wi-Fi Connection.The Check is done initialy but i need to confirm that download is happening on Wi-Fi and should be cancelled if the user has switched to 3G/4G while app is in Background.

Comment: isn't the download canceled anyway, because your IP address has changed?

Comment: So if im keeping a long runnning download process in background and if  Wi-Fi goes and come backs after a few minutes will i be able to start the download in background itself?

Comment: i don't know, try it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to make sure downloads only happen on WiFi, then you should set the `allowsCellularAccess` property of the NSURLSession's [NSURLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSessionConfiguration) to  `NO`.

No monitoring, cancelling or other tricks needed: that'll make sure the download never goes over the cellular connection.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this library

- [Rechability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

It uses NSNotification, and you can make some changes in it if you need to set it your way

This is a example code provided by this library

```
// Allocate a reachability object
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

// Tell the reachability that we DON'T want to be reachable on 3G/EDGE/CDMA
reach.reachableOnWWAN = NO;

// Here we set up a NSNotification observer. The Reachability that caused the notification
// is passed in the object parameter
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) 
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                           object:nil];

[reach startNotifier];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Will this notification be available while the app is still in background?

Comment: In fact I have no used the library when app is on background, since there are some limitations but have a look here for that issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323634/ios-application-executing-tasks-in-background

Comment: Im using NSURLSession to download the files.So the app is downloading large files in background.

Comment: I checked some forums and tutorials and they say that https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NewsstandKit_Framework/_index.html is the one for processing downloads on background, and you can manipulate it to work with NSNotifications on your own. Hope it hels