# Monitor content displayed on iPhone's screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, screen, monitor

I want to monitor the iPhone's screen in background, whenever the content displayed on the phone window was changed, the app will send out a notification.

For example, if I open Stack Overflow in Safari, when the page is loading or some Flash on the page is animating, I will receive the notification. But I don't know how to detect the event.

Comment: I do not think what you're trying to achieve is possible due to Apple's architecture, but have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323634/ios-application-executing-tasks-in-background

Comment: thanks! my question is how to detect the content on the screen is changed.